# Insider trading in another company?

Tags: united-states, stocks, canada, legal, insider-trading

Suppose that, as an insider in Company A, I become aware of an upcoming business move by Company A that will have a huge *negative* impact on its share price, and a similar huge *positive* impact on the share price of Company B, the only major competitor to Company A. (Think just ceasing operation without any public warning.)

Clearly I can't dump my Company A stock, or short sell Company A, without violating insider trading regulations.

But can I buy a bunch of Company B?  I have no insider information on Company B, or do I?

Comment: This is more of a legal question.  However, I believe the relevant factor is not whether you have information "about Company B", but simply whether you have non-public information which is relevant to your trade.

Comment: An example of trading on material non-public information in a company other than the one you work for: http://www.reuters.com/article/2014/08/08/insidertrading-seattle-idUSL2N0QD26220140808

Comment: `I become aware` This is am important point. How did you deduce the information ? If deduced from all public information this isn't insider trading. But if some component is from inside sources obtained privately this is indeed insider trading.

Comment: @DumbCoder: Hypothetically,  I ***work*** in the head office of Company A.  I may have helped decide on the course of action that will hammer the shares of Company A.  I may own shares of Company A, and clearly I could not trade in ***them***.  But I have no information from ***within*** Company B, whose shares I want to buy...

Answer (score 6):

This information is clearly "material" (large impact) and "non-public" according to the statement of the problem.  Also, decisions like [United States v. Carpenter](https://www.sec.gov/news/speech/speecharchive/1998/spch221.htm) make it clear that you do not need to be a member of the company to do illegal insider trading on its stock.

Importantly though, [stackexchange is not a place for legal advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148725/law-stackexchange-com) and this answer should not be construed as such.  Legal/compliance at Company A would be a good place to start asking questions.